# No rollback for ConstraintViolationException in transactional service

Tags: spring, rollback, transactional

I've a service method called `add()` which is annotated with `@Transactional`.

I call it but when a ConstraintViolationException occurs inside corresponding DAO method it'll rollback the transaction even when I specify not to.

I expect that `ConstraintViolationException` to be caught and instead of it `NotFoundException` checked exception would be thrown.

```
@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = ConstraintViolationException.class)
public User add(User user) throws NotFoundException {
    try {
        result = userDao.add(user);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Couldn't find group");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to catch `ConstraintViolationException` without transaction rollback?

I'm using spring 3.1.1 and hibernate 3.6.

Comment: You're specifying that there should be no rollback for ConstraintViolationException. But the exception which is thrown is a NotFoundException. Since it's a checked exception, it should not cause a rollback *by default*. But it all depends how you configured the Spring transaction manager.

Comment: I want to catch ConstraintViolationException and throw NotFoundException but catch block doesn't catch it, I think it might be catched by proxy before it reaches the catch block, so ConstraintViolationException goes up and transaction rollbacks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I see what happens. The ConstraintViolationException happens at commit time, after the method has been executed, when the transaction interceptor around your `add()` method tries to commit the transaction. Since it can't commit, obviously, the transaction is rollbacked. It can't to anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes i think it should be it.

Comment: Hi @JB Nizet, so you actually mean, that if an exception occurs at commit time, there is nothing you can do to prevent it? Like property noRollbackFor would not have any power on stopping that? I am having a similar situation where I am trying to catch an ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException. –