# Spring 3 and noRollbackFor = Exception.class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a method that is annotated as following:

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

When inside this method happens a NullPointerException the noRollbackFor seems to work and the transaction is not marked as rollbackOnly, but if the exception is something like:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

then the transaction is marked as rollbackOnly.

Is there a way to make the second case works as the first?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using JPA + Hibernate

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777666/no-rollback-for-constraintviolationexception-in-transactional-service