# Spring - Cannot catch ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a method in my service:

```
@Transactional
    public MyResponse create(UserCredentials cred) {
        User user = new User(cred);
        try {
            final User created = userRepository.save(user);
            return new MyResponse(user, "Created");
        } catch (TransactionSystemException e) {
            return new MyResponse(null, "Cannot create");
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            return new MyResponse(null, "Cannot create");
        }
    }
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false,
            nullable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(
            nullable = false,
            unique = true
    )
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(
            nullable = false,
            unique = true
    )
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
```

And the problem is when I send in JSON empty username or empty email. When I debug application I get ConstraintViolationExcpetion, but in JSON response I get:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1500026388864,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException",
    "message": "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly",
    "path": "/register"
}
```

Debugger is stopping at catch(ConstraintViolationException e), but finally I get SystemTransactionException, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No rollback for ConstraintViolationException in transactional service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777666/no-rollback-for-constraintviolationexception-in-transactional-service)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catch the exception above. Out of the method annotated with `@Transactional`.

In you case you intercept the exception and swallow but DB state is still incorrect. So on attempt to commit after the exit of annotated method it fails.

Or add an ExceptionHandler to catch this exception and return correct response.

Comment: I removed annotation @Transactional and now it works. Why?

Comment: Using `@Transactional` makes Spring catch any unchecked exceptions and deal with them internally by rolling back any incomplete database transactions, so it won't let you catch the exception. Removing `@Transactional` means you have to deal with any unchecked exceptions yourself, meaning you can catch the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

> Debugger is stopping at catch(ConstraintViolationException e), but finally I get SystemTransactionException, why?

This is due to Spring's **exception translation** mechanism whereby Spring wraps up any underlying exceptions in one of it's own RuntimeException classes.

Seems odd at first, but changes to underlying JPA providers or even changing databases can (commonly) throw different exception types for the same failure conditions.

- You only need to worry about handling Spring exceptions, and not the range of exceptions that underlying technologies may throw
- Checked exceptions are mapped to unchecked exceptions so you don't have to pepper your code with try-catch blocks.
- Much easier to translate exceptions onto server response codes (in your case the translation to 500 was automatic).

Hope this helps.

**[afterthought]** Worth a mention, that Spring will perform this translation **after** it's invoked your transactional method which is why you never catch the `TransactionSystemException`

Comment: The last paragraph about Spring doing the translation after the transactional method saved me hours.